# Saving Node Js Access Logs To MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, morgan

I have setup the package [mongo-morgan-ext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-morgan-ext) to save access logs to mongodb. This package relies on morgan internally. The problem I am facing is that it is not saving custom headers that are being sent in the request. It just saves everything else which is standard. Has anyone done this using morgan or any other package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explicitly defined in the code, see [here](https://github.com/serganus/mongo-morgan-ext/blob/master/index.js#L18-L63).

So you can edit it and add what you want to fetch:

```
'REQUEST': {
    'Accept': tokens['req'](req, res, 'Accept'),
    'x-api-version': tokens['req'](req, res, 'x-api-version'),  //custom
    'client-id': tokens['req'](req, res, 'client-id'),          //custom
    ...
```

Comment: Already did that an deploy. But thanks for the answer anyways.